# Injection of a provider from the same module: can't resolve dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

### Bug Report

### Current behavior

Getting error while instantiating the PaymentProcessorModule:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PaymentProcessor (?, PaymentsService, ProcessingService). Please make sure that the argument TransactionsService at index [0] is available in the PaymentProcessor context.

Potential solutions:
- If TransactionsService is a provider, is it part of the current PaymentProcessor?
- If TransactionsService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within PaymentProcessor?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing TransactionsService */ ]
  })
```

However, both services come from the same module.

### Input Code

Here's my module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ Transaction ]),
  ],
  providers: [
    PaymentProcessor,
    TransactionsService,

    TransactionsResolver,
  ],
  exports: [PaymentProcessor],
})
export class PaymentProcessorModule {}
```

TransactionService:

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Transaction) private transRepo: Repository<Transaction>,
  ) {}

  //...
}
```

And finally, PaymentProcessor:

```
@Injectable()
export class PaymentProcessor {
  constructor(
    private transactions: TransactionsService,
    private payments: PaymentsService,
    private processor: ProcessingService,
  ) {}

  //...
}
```

### Expected behavior

Expected to inject the TransactionsService. I could not seem to reproduce it in a sample repo, unfortunately.

### Environment

```
Nest version: 7.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The official support of NestJS told me that the `PaymentProcessor` must be mentioned in the `imports` array somewhere. I checked for usages of the class and it's true, I accidentally imported the provider instead of the module in another context.